# htmx link autofresh until output does not change

Tags: htmx

If I press this hx-get link I get the updated time without refreshing the entire page.

```html
<td style="White-space: nowrap;">
  <div hx-get="/jobtime/2416" hx-swap="outerHTML" class="">157.0</div>
</td>
```

Is it possible to auto-load this url like every 1minute, with a check that if it does not increase we stop?

```html
<td style="White-space: nowrap;">
  <div hx-get="/jobtime/2416" 
      hx-swap="outerHTML"
      class=""
      hx-trigger="every 60s [someConditional]"
  >157.0</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you no longer want to continue auto-load, you can return specifc response code to make it stop.

Please refer to this section:
https://htmx.org/docs/#polling

> If you want to stop polling from a server response you can respond with the HTTP response code 286 and the element will cancel the polling.

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned polling in the trigger section